# Google Coral - Update OS Offline

Tags: debian, google-coral

I have a Coral dev-board and I installed Mendel Chef successfully by flashing from the SD Card. I found out that the Mendel Day has the better CURL library that I would like to update the OS for the new features.

I wonder if there is any way that I can update the OS through USB or not. I know that I can install the package only but very nice if I can update the whole OS.

Answer (score 0):

The sd-card image is only needed as a recovery image to back back on uboot if something goes wrong during flashing. You should be able to flash the image without needing to use the sdcard at all following this:
https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/reflash/#flash-a-new-system-image

FYI, we are on to mendel5.0 Eagle now :)
https://coral.ai/news/updates-07-2020/

Comment: Thanks you for your response but I did not describe my situation clearly. I want to update the OS by itself without using second station. I tried to flash the image which I had cloned from another board from the USB but it does not work for all of my tries. Do you have other suggestion?